# Custom visitor pattern implementation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface, visitor-pattern

I'm trying to implement a sort of visitor pattern. Most of examples on web show a visitor class with a "visit" method and multiple overloads of that method. In this case i've called my "visit" method CalculateFee (it's a semantic matter) with its overloads. Everything it's ok so far, but now i need to implement a visitor again to execute another method "CalculateExtraCharge", so i have added another method called CalculateExtraCharge with its overloads. But now i have two questions

1) Is this a wrong implementation of the pattern?

2) Should i always call my method "visit"?

Here is an overview of my code, i have omited some parts of it to focus only in what is important for my question.

```
    public class CreditCard : IPaymentMethod
    {
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public decimal GetFee(IPaymentCalculationsVisitor visitor)
        {
            return visitor.CalculateFee(this);
        }

        public decimal GetExtraCharge(IPaymentCalculationsVisitor visitor)
        {
            return visitor.CalculateExtraCharge(this);
        }

    }

    public class Check : IPaymentMethod
    {
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public decimal GetFee(IPaymentCalculationsVisitor visitor)
        {
            return visitor.CalculateFee(this);
        }

        public decimal GetExtraCharge(IPaymentCalculationsVisitor visitor)
        {
            return visitor.CalculateExtraCharge(this);
        }
    }

    public interface IPaymentCalculationsVisitor
    {
        decimal CalculateFee(CreditCard creditCard);
        decimal CalculateFee(Check check);

        decimal CalculateExtraCharge(CreditCard creditCard);
        decimal CalculateExtraCharge(Check check);
    }

    public class PaymentCalculationsVisitor: IPaymentCalculationsVisitor
    {

        public decimal CalculateFee(CreditCard creditCard)
        {
            return creditCard.Amount * 0.15m;

        }

        public decimal CalculateFee(Check check)
        {
            return check.Amount * 0.10m;
        }

        public decimal CalculateExtraCharge(CreditCard creditCard)
        {
            return 15;
        }

        public decimal CalculateExtraCharge(Check check)
        {
            return 10;
        }

    }

    public class PaymentProcessor
    {

        public void ProcessPayment()
        {
            var paymentMethods = new List<IPaymentMethod>()
            {
                new CreditCard(),
                new Check()
            };

            var calculationsVisitor = new PaymentCalculationsVisitor();

            foreach (var paymentMethod in paymentMethods)
            {

                //First i need to get the fee
                var fee = paymentMethod.GetFee(calculationsVisitor);

                //Then i do do some other stuff, validations, other calculations etc

                //Finally i get the extra charge
                var extraCharge = paymentMethod.GetExtraCharge(calculationsVisitor);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Please see the edited paragraph in my answer. While adding a second visit method to the `IPaymentMethod` hierarchy will work, a feature of the pattern is to allow new visitor logic without having to modify the visited types. That is the reason a single visit method is most common. There's nothing wrong with two visit methods, but the pattern is designed to avoid having to add more methods. Instead, you create new visitor classes and pass them to the existing visit method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is this a wrong implementation of the pattern?

No, this is still the GoF Visitor Pattern. The capability of `IPaymentCalculationsVisitor` to visit two different methods doesn't change the nature of the pattern. Because it combines the logic for two different visits, you may want to think about the SOLID principles, however.

- Are both methods part of a *Single Responsibility*, i.e. will they both change for the same reasons, or would one method potentially change independently of the other?
- Will potential clients always depend on both methods? *Interface Segregation* would decouple `CalculateFee` and `CalculateExtraCharge` so clients could have one without the other.

Do note the Visitor Pattern can allow new behavior to be added to the `IPaymentMethod` type hierarchy without having to modify the child classes such as `CreditCard` and `Check`. By splitting the visitor interface into `FeeVisitor` and `ExtraChargeVisitor`, both could be passed into a single visit method.

> 2) Should i always call my method "visit"?

No, in any design pattern, you may name your methods whatever you like. It's most important that the code has meaning to you and to its domain. For the sake of a common vocabulary with other developers, you may consider adding documentation using the pattern's published terminology, if you think that would clarify the code's intent.

Comment: If `CreditCard` exposes all required data(through properties or methods), then why I need to use "Visitor" pattern, instead `PaymentProcessor` just call `var fee = calculationsVisitor.CalculateFee(creditCard)` (Remove prefix "...Visitor"). Code would be simpler and `CreditCard` don't need to have dependency on `IPaymentCalculationsVisitor`

Comment: Visitor allows a collection of `IPaymentMethod` to be handled uniformly. If you know the concrete type of an object, then you can treat it accordingly. If you only know its interface, the visitor can apply type-specific behavior without casting or branching.

Comment: In OP case visitor depends on concrete type `CreditCard`, `Check`. CreditCard only passing itself to the `IPaymentCalculations`, this job can be done by `PaymentProcessor`, where all dependencies already exists.

Comment: A visitor interface always depends on the concrete types of the hierarchy it visits. That's part of the double-dispatch it provides. [Sourcemaking](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) is a great resource for pattern definitions and examples.

Comment: If you forget for a second about patterns, and think about the code where you passing `IPaymentCalculationsVisitor` to the `CredtCard`, only for `CreditCard` to pass itself to the `IPaymentCalculationsVisitor`. Why you need to introduce extra level of indirection, where instead you simply do `var fee = paymentCalculations.calculateFeeFor(creditCard);` in `PaymentProcessor` class?

Comment: While this answer is "by a book", @Fabio answer has more sense in object-oriented world (or I would say Message oriented).

Answer (score 3):

> 2) Should i always call my method "visit"?

No, name method in more domain specific way.

> 1) Is this a wrong implementation of the pattern?

Looking at your implementation, I found it little bit different.

```
public class CreditCard : IPaymentMethod
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public decimal GetFee(IPaymentCalculationsVisitor visitor)
    {
        return visitor.CalculateFee(this);
    }

    public decimal GetExtraCharge(IPaymentCalculationsVisitor visitor)
    {
        return visitor.CalculateExtraCharge(this);
    }
}
```

One of the Object-oriented programming is encapsulation, where object owes its data (not exposed to outside world).
With Visitor pattern we can provide extra functionality to the object without exposing it's data outside.

Because internal data not exposed to the outside of the object, visitor need to "visit inside the object", where object will be able to provide required values to the visitor without exposing those values outside(without making those values public).

For question's case we can pass calculator(visitor) into `CreditCard` class, where calculator will takes only required data as arguments (notice only required values - not whole object).

```
public class CreditCard : IPaymentMethod
{
    // Following OOP principles and keep data private
    private decimal _amount;

    public CreditCard(decimal amount) => _amount;

    public decimal GetFee(IPaymentCalculationsVisitor visitor)
    {
        return visitor.CalculateFee(_amount); // provide only required data
    }

    public decimal GetExtraCharge(IPaymentCalculationsVisitor visitor)
    {
        return visitor.CalculateExtraCharge(_amount); // provide only required data
    }
}
```

With such approach, calculator(visitor) class will not depend on the classes it can visit. Actually it can visit any class which can provide required information.

In your particular case where `CreditCard` exposes data(having public property `Amount`) - you can remove redundant step and pass credit card object straight to the calculations

```
 public void ProcessPayment()
 {
     var paymentMethods = new List<IPaymentMethod>()
     {
            new CreditCard(),
            new Check()
     };

     var calculations = new PaymentCalculationsVisitor();

     foreach (var paymentMethod in paymentMethods)
     {
        //First i need to get the fee
        var fee = calculations.GetFee(paymentMethod);

        //Then i do do some other stuff, validations, other calculations etc

        //Finally i get the extra charge
        var extraCharge = calculations.GetExtraCharge(paymentMethod);
    }
}
```